# How do you replace an entire xaml element?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTempalte x:Key="label">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}"/>
        </DataTEmplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="editor">
            <UserControl Content="{Binding Control.content}"/> <!-- This is the line -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource label}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" CellTemplate="{StaticResource editor}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

On the marketed line, I'm replacing the contents of a UserControl with the contents of another UserControl that is dynamically created in code.  **I'd like to replace the entire control, and not just the content.  Is there a way to do this?**

Edit:

To clarify my intent, the `Items` that my `ListView` collection holds owns a Control (which inherits from `UserControl`) that knows how to manipulate the item's value.  Simply binding the Content gets me the visual representation, but discards other non-content related properties of the derived Control.  If I could replace that UserControl in my template in a more whole-sale fashion, this would fix that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this one out:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="editor">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Control}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to switch between label and textbox in a cell based on some state.  I'd use trigger for that.

Or see if this might be of use: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/editabletextblock.aspx

Updated:

Here's a hack (I don't recommend this and I hate myself a little for posting it):

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="editor">
        <Border Loaded="Border_Loaded">
            <UserControl Content="{Binding Control.content}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

In code behind:

```
    private void Border_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Example of replacement
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Content = "Woot!";
        ((Border)sender).Child = b;
    }
```

Obviously, you'll need to store the reference to the border and keep track of which border belongs to which cell.  I can't imagine this is less complex than switching templates.

Comment: Interesting link, but this isn't what I'm trying to achieve.  I'd like to replace that UserControl with another, arbitrary UserControl.

Comment: Would switching templates on the fly work in this situation?  See here for details http://codingbandit.com/Blog/blog/wpf-data-templates-part-3-switching-data-templates-at-runtime/.

There is a way to do what you want, but it's kludgey and I suspect not the best approach to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Switching templates on the the fly is what I had been doing originally.  Switching the UserControl simplifies what I was doing greatly.